# Give a specific user role the ability to give a user a role but not the 'administrator' role

Tags: 7, users

I have a set up using drupal 7 where, as a super administrator, I can add a user with a role of 'manager' (who can also add users to his shop) but I want to also give 'manager' the ability to specify if the user he wants to add will have either of the two simple roles (one to create/add data and one to view reports on sales only) say, 'sales-agent', 'sales-report'. Currently, in my setup, the manager can specify all roles including the 'administrator' role which I should have access only as a developer/super admin.

I have been looking around for modules to fit this but my time is running out.

Thanks for all your help. Drupal is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a perfect module for you - [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) - and there is a stable 7.x release as well. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... allows site administrators to grant some roles the authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role permission to allow the assignment of that role.

Comment: speaking of perfect this is really awesome! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to create 2 (not global) flags, with these details:

- These flags will be used to flag *users* (not nodes or something).
- Say you label those flags ***Create/add data*** and ***View reports***.
- Only users who have role ***manager*** are allowed to use these flags (something you can specify when configuring these flags).

Create a 1st rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) like so:

- Rules Event: User gets flagged by the ***View reports*** flag.
- Rules Action: Grant Access to your role to ***View reports***.

Create a 2nd rule that is similar to the 1st rule, but now for the ***Create/add data*** (flag and role).

#### Possible improvements

You could take this even a step further, also using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules): Create a 3rd (and 4th) rule with Rules Event "User is unflagged", and trigger a Rules Action "Remove access to the role corresponding to the flag".

If you want, you can even consolidate these 4 rules in a single rule, using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module.

#### Avoid modulitis

With the above approach, you reduce the risk your site starts to suffer modulitis (= way too much contributed modules that only do 1 specific thing). Because chances are that you already use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in your site, maybe also [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) already. And if you're not using these modules yet, you'll find dozens of other use-cases for those 2 modules ... and possibly get rid of even more contributed modules that only do 1 thing (what else can you use the [Role delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module for?).